# Web page indexed 2 days ago via google seach console but not found in google search

Tags: seo

here is the link I submitted https://www.newsserver.net/what-requires-mental-work-what-requires-physical-work-and-what-requires-both/

The situation is if the page has been indexed it should show somewhere in google search, however it is no where to be seen, even by using different search terms, please advise.

Answer (score 2):

To check

- Go to `google.com` in your browser
- Type in `site:newsserver.net` in the google search box
- The page is number 5 in the list.  It is indexed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is indexed Google search will show it but maybe in the last page. To be on the first pages you need strong in page seo and off page seo... and good marketing of your page in social media...
You Can still check that it is présent in Google search by doing in Google search bar
Site: https..yourwebpage